# Concurrent iteration and thread safety

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm reading B. Goetz Java Concurrency In Practice and now I'm at the section about thread-safe collections. He described the so-called "hidden iterators" which may throw `ConcurrentModificationException`. Here is the example he dispensed:

```
public class HiddenIterator{

    @GuardedBy("this")
    private final Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();

    public synchronized void add(Integer i){ set.add(i); }
    public synchronized void remove(Integer i){ set.remove(i); }

    public void addTenThings(){
        Random r = new Random();
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            add(r.nextInt());
        System.out.println("DEBUG: added ten elements to set " + set)
    }
}
```

Now, it's obviously that `addTenThings()` may throw `ConcurrentModificationException` as that printing `set`'s content involves iterating it. But he provide the following suggestion for dealing with it:

> If HiddenIterator wrapped the HashSet with a synchronizedSet,
>   encapsulating the synchronization, this sort of error would not occur.

I don't quite understand it. Even if we wrapped `set` into a synchronized-wrapper, the class would still remain `NotThreadSafe`. What did he mean?

Comment: He meant that a ConcurrentModificationException would not occur anymore. Why do you think the inverse is true?

Comment: The synchronization wrappers add ***automatic synchronization*** (thread-safety) to an arbitrary collection

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because `Collections.synchronizedSet` synchronizes *every* method, including `toString`. Indeed, if you tried to iterate over a wrapped set *manually*, you could get `ConcurrentModificationException`, so you have to synchronize manual iteration yourself. But methods that do hidden iterations already do it, so you don't have to worry about that at least. Here is the corresponding piece of code from the JDK sources:

```
public String toString() {
    synchronized (mutex) {return c.toString();}
}
```

Here, `mutex` is initialized to `this` in the constructor of the wrapper class, so it's basically `synchronized (this)`.

Comment: yes the iterator of `synchronizedSet` is not thread safe and requires manual synchronization. Please read post here: http://aadityasg.github.io/Java-Synchronized-Collections-and-Thread-Safety/

Comment: @AadityaGavandalkar, that's exactly what I said: manual iteration requires manual synchronization. But the collection methods that do iteration synchronize it so you no longer have to do it yourself.

Comment: Yes I know. I was just commenting and was not highlighting it as a mistake :)